# Send an HTML email using SMTP

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

Here is my php code to send SMTP email that contains HTML:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{ 
    $email_message = "Hello World\n\n";
    $email_message .= "<h2>hello</h2>";
    $to = $_POST['reci'];
    $from = $email;
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $email_message;
    $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
    $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
} else {
    header('Location: XX');
}
```

I want to sent 'hello' word in h2 tag, but i receive just

```
<h2>hello</h2>
```

and it is not an HTML code, it returns just like a text.

here is smtp.php file:

```
 class SMTPClient
{

function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
{
$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
$this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;
$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;
    if ($SmtpPort == "") 
    {
    $this->PortSMTP = 25;
        }else{
    $this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
    }
}
function SendMail ()
{
    if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
    {

           fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n");  
           $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 

           fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
           $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
            fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
            $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);

            fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
            $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);

           fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n");  
           $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 );  
           fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n");  
           $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 

           fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
            $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
            fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
            $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
           fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n");  
           fclose($SMTPIN); 
    }
return $talk;
}
}
```

in this case i must change the smtp.php source code, but how can i add MIME encoding and Content-Type: text/html in header?

Comment: Your email needs MIME encoding and `Content-Type: text/html` to show html. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME This might happen in 'smtp.php' but we cannot see that.

Comment: this code works good, but i can just send a normal text email, and i want to include HTML inside that
the function is in included file named smtp.php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i added my smtp.php source

Comment: Thanks. Yes, MIME is missing. So add it, or use a library that has it, like phpmailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware
but i don't know how to add MIME from a library?

Comment: You cannot add MIME from a library to your 'smtp.php', you have to use the library instead of your own php file. Alternatively you could add MIME encoding to your file, but this is not easy, and explaining it is not suitable for an answer on stackoverflow. Just google it. Remember that even a space in the wrong place, or an missing empty line, can invalidate a MIME encoding, better use the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$headers = array ('MIME-Version' => '1.0rn',
    'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rn",
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
 );
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks